# ERRO: cannot convert from 'int' to 'CRUD.Models.Times'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, crud

olá! estou fazendo um projeto de crud em asp net mvc e meu código apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to
> 'CRUD.Models.Times'

Esse erro se dá quando vou passar o parametro id pra dentro do try.

```
public ActionResult ExcluirTime(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                _repositorio = new TimeRepositorio();
                if(_repositorio.ExcluirTime(id)) //o erro se dá no id
                {
                    ViewBag.Message("Time excluído com sucesso!");
                }
                return RedirectToAction("MostrarTimes");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("MostrarTimes");
            }
        }
```

Classe ExcluirTime

```
public bool ExcluirTime(Times objTimes)
        {
            int i;
            Connection();
            using(SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("ExcluirTime", _con))
            {
                consulta.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _con.Open();
                consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", objTimes.cd_time);
                i = consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
            };
            _con.Close();
            if(i >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Coloque também a função `ExcluirTime` da classe `TimeRepositorio` na sua pergunta para podermos te ajudar

Comment: pronto, coloquei

Comment: A função espera um objeto do tipo `Times` e não um id, você precisa procurar dentre todos os times aquele que possui o id desejado e só depois passar esse time como parâmetro da função

Comment: agora foi! obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método em seu repositório não espera um argumento `int` que no seu caso é o Id.
Você pode alterar o método para receber o parâmetro correto e assim evitar de realizar uma outra consulta apenas ou instanciar um novo objeto só para realizar essa operação.
E recomendaria mudar um pouco para não precisar fechar a conexão manualmente, mas para isso seria necessário ver como você está controlando isso.

```
public bool ExcluirTime(int cd_time)
{
    int i;

    Connection();
    using(SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("ExcluirTime", _con))
    {
        consulta.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _con.Open();
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", cd_time);
        i = consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
    };
    _con.Close();
    if(i >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigada! era isso mesmo